# How to create multiple gridviews dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create multiple gridviews?

My code:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
Panel PNl = new Panel();

for (int i = 0; i < DST.Tables.Count; i++)
{            
    gv.ID = DST.Tables[i].TableName;
    gv.DataSource = DST.Tables[i];
    gv.DataBind();
    // form.Controls.Add(gv);     
    PNl.Controls.Add(gv);     
}

//gv.Parent.Controls.Add(form);

form.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
form.Controls.Add(PNl);
this.Controls.Add(form);
```

However, my code is creating only one grid view.

Comment: Can you use something like `GridView[] gv` and assign each table to the gridview?

Comment: because you are using the same instance of the GV. Create a new instance inside your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of the GridView inside the loop. This way you will create many grids and not just reuse one object. In practice you probably want to create a user control with the grid and use that since you will be able to specify different grid attributes in markup which is easier than specifying them in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=10;
```

GridView[] gc = new GridView[i];

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        gc[i] = new GridView();
        gc[i].ID = "gv" + i;
        gc[i].CopyBaseAttributes(GridView1);
        gc[i].AlternatingRowStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle);
        gc[i].BorderStyle = GridView1.BorderStyle;
        gc[i].ControlStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.ControlStyle);
        gc[i].EditRowStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.EditRowStyle);
        gc[i].EmptyDataRowStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.EmptyDataRowStyle);
        gc[i].FooterStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.FooterStyle);
        gc[i].HeaderStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.HeaderStyle);
        gc[i].RowStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.RowStyle);
        gc[i].SelectedRowStyle.CopyFrom(GridView1.SelectedRowStyle);
        gc[i].ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
        gc[i].RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Gv_RowDataBound);
        //gc[i].EmptyDataText = "No ROWS Found in the particular month";
        }
```

Have GridView1 in design page and set visible to false, so you can copy properties.